# Ruby : Conditional initialization

Tags: ruby

I've read about conditional initialization in Ruby and

```
obj1 ||= Class1.new
```

is same as

```
obj1 ||obj1 = Class1.new
```

as everything is Ruby is an Object, I wonder why the following phrase raises a "NameError: undefined method or name...":

```
x || x = 10
```

but

```
x ||= 10
```

is a correct statement

Comment: what makes you think is is incorrect? Are you getting an error, or just a result you don't expect? In which case, precedence rules are the key.

Comment: @JezC `x || x = 10` raises a `NameError` if `x` is undefined whereas `x ||= 10` does not.

Comment: I've always thought of it as being roughly equivalent to `obj1 = obj1 || Class1.new`, except when `obj1` is allowed to be `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first form, `x` is referenced first independently. Unlike the second form, `x` needs to be defined first or else it would raise an error.

```
> x = nil
=> nil
> x || x = 10
=> 10
```

The form `x ||= 10` combines declaration and testing at the same time, so it doesn't generate an error whether `x` was already declared earlier or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
defined?(x) || something
```

In your example, x does not exist. So you can't test what its' value is. Check to see whether it is defined. You can go further:

```
defined?(x) && x.nil? || x = 10
```

This will check to see if x is defined. If not, it will set x to 10. If x is defined, but has a nil value (also not useful), then x is also set to 10.

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought of it as being equivalent to `obj1 = obj1 || Class1.new`, rather than `obj1 || obj1 = Class1.new`. This interpretation is more correct because it doesn't raise a `NameError`, and is consistent with the behavior of other operators which combine with `=`:

```
number = 1
number += 2 #=> 3
number -= 5 #=> -2
number *= 2 #=> -4
number /= 2 #=> -2
number **= 2 #=> 4

boolean = false
boolean ||= false #=> false
boolean ||= true #=> true
boolean &&= true #=> true
boolean &&= false #=> false
boolean &&= false #=> false

string = ""
string += "Hello" #=> "Hello"
string += ", world!" #=> "Hello, world!"
```

As for why `obj1 || obj1 = Class1.new` raises a `NameError`, it's because the part of that statement before the `||` operator is trying to reference `obj1` before it's defined. `obj1 = obj1 || Class1.new` doesn't do that because it starts the assignment before referencing `obj1`.